# Can I defeat Spiked Beetles without a shield?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-seasons

I am working on the sixth dungeon, and there is a room with Spiked Beetles that look like this:

[image]

I know that you are supposed to hit them with a shield and then you can hit them with your sword and kill them.

Problem is, I keep losing my shield in the Lost Woods before I can even get back to this dungeon, so I have bought 4 shields in a row and it is tiring having to go back and forth and raise rupees to buy one only to lose it before I get to the temple.

Is there an alternate way to flip these guys/defeat them that doesn't require a shield that I keep losing to Like-Likes?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think you get your shield back if you kill the like-like that stole your shield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be flipped using either the shovel (with some timing) or the gale seeds also work

Additionally, (though not quite on-topic), you can use the like-like ring which can be obtained in Gasha seeds, mini-games or Maple meetings, to transform into a like-like, thus becoming impervious to being eaten and having your items stolen.

Answer (score 1):

Ben is right about what you can use to defeat the spiked beetles.

You can also use a Gale Seed to go back to the dungeon once you've been there (there's a seed tree right below it). No need to go through the forest again.

Comment: I do not know what your talking about with the gale seeds. I just tried in this same dungeon and it didn't work.